# Basic Auth / Restricting backend admin panel for M1

Tags: magento-1, backend, security, nginx, two-factor-authentication

Good evening.

Should it not be possible toeither restrict or use basic auth on the admin panel for login? Just as an extra security layer.

Can there be any flaws/errors regadring 3rd party extentions like payments, tracking etc? Or does it depend on what URI / API the extentions are using? Otherwise is there anything else to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I think no - And I will recommend you to add 2FA on the Login page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - we already have 2FA, we just want another layer.

Comment: Then you can restrict IP address for accessing the admin panel using .htaccess.